# A Fast Way to Determine Whether A Componet is Found In JPanel

Tags: java, swing

May I know how can I determine whether a component is found in JPanel?

```
boolean isThisComponentFoundInJPanel(Component c)
{
    Component[] components = jPanel.getComponents();
    for (Component component : components) {
        if (c== component) {
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Using loop is not efficient. Is there any better way?

Comment: No. Is merely based on 'false' technical reason. In order to get >1st depth level parent-child relationship, I have use to recursive call to achieve. At the time I read Tom Hawtin's, my first thought is getComponents will return >1st depth level children (which is not true). Hence, I first thought it is more straight forward than yours, and this makes me click on accept it as answer without much thought. Is my mistake. The answer shall go to yours :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
if (c.getParent() == jPanel)
```

Call recursively if you don't want immediate parent-child relationships (which is probably the case in a well-designed panel).

... although in a well-designed panel, it's very questionable why you'd need to know whether a component is contained in the panel.

Comment: +1 for "... although in a well-designed panel, it's very questionable why you'd need to know whether a component is contained in the panel."

Comment: Is a dynamic panel a poorly designed panel?

Comment: There are no one rule that fit for all. Use common sense. Dynamic panel is good and my users is happy about it, and dynamic panel need to discover parent/ child dynamically during run-time. As along as my users is happy, it is nothing to be questionable when I need to know whether a component is contained in the panel.

Answer (score 10):

you can use

```
jPanel.isAncestorOf(component)
```

for recursive search

Answer (score 5):

Performance of this operation is highly unlikely to be a bottleneck.

Looking through the contents of a container probably indicates bad design. Tell the GUI what to do, don't interrogate its state.

Probably a better way to write the code is to use existing routines. Whilst there is some overhead, they are more likely to be already compiled (therefore possibly faster) and are less code.

```
boolean isComponentInPanel(Component component) {
    return
        java.util.Arrays.asList(panel.getComponents())
            .contains(component);
}
```

(Or use kdgregory's answer.)